# Should rollbacks be visible to everybody?

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request, rollbacks

While looking at a question, OP edited it to add some additional code, but there was one issue: the new code included the names, gender, and phone numbers of real people from their database.

I decided to do a rollback to the previous version, but **rollbacks do not remove/hide the latest edit from the stack, they add a new edit with the selected version** of the question. That is understandable, as you want to keep track of all changes, but it is a problem too as now even anonymous visitors (or web crawlers) can check the question history, and see personal information from certain people*.

I don't know how common this issue is, but it isn't the only case I've seen on SO in which passwords, API codes, or other private information that should not be public are displayed because the user posted it by mistake.

**Is it possible to limit who can see the rollbacks?** (or to be correct, the previous version of a rollback). I think it would be a good idea to limit it to the owner and previous editors of the post and to registered users with a minimum reputation.

Seeing rollbacks could turn into a new privilege (or directly be included in the [Edit Questions And Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) one), and it would not interfere with the user's ability of editing/rolling back posts, just with the capacity to see other users' rollbacks.

---

[* Note: since this particular case happened, OP's edit was removed from the revision history by the moderators, and it's no longer available for regular users to see.]

Comment: And what if the original version contained this info and it was edited out not with a rollback?  How do we determine what should and shouldn't be visible? Just flag it for mod attention.

Comment: This suggestion wouldn't work with edits, just rollbacks.

Comment: SO gets scraped by dozens of vampire sites.  There is no point in trying to hide anything.

Answer (score 13):

Revisions should remain in history so that everyone can see them. **HOWEVER**, if personal information is included in a revision, the post should be [flagged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132117/what-should-i-do-if-a-user-posts-sensitive-information-as-part-of-a-question-or) so that a specific revision can be removed. The moderators will have to raise the issue with the community managers or developers to get a revision removed.

Comment: How about the cases that don't get flagged or that people don't see?

Comment: It's not mine or Stack Exchange's job to protect the data of your (generic 'your') customers. If you post the data publicly, it's on you and your company to resolve it. SE provides a way to do that by purging the revision history.

Comment: I understand and agree with that. Still, when it's not your mistake, you would not want to have your data available online; and flag moderation is not an automatic thing

Comment: And how do you suggest making it automatic? How do you recommend SE figure out the difference between authentic and dummy data?

Comment: Who suggested making it automatic? I certainly didn't

Comment: My suggestion is to hide the content of a rollback to low-reputation/unregistered viewers. Right now, during the time that a post is flagged, until it is moderated, the content of the rollback is visible to everybody.